# Systematically Hyperlinking text in Word VBA

Tags: vba, hyperlink, range, selection, ms-word

I work for a company that does custom reports in Microsoft Word very frequently.  I would like to write a VBA Macro that systematically goes through the following list and Hyperlinks ONLY the text (not paragraph symbols or tab arrows or list number) and links to a bookmark in the current document.

```
1 → Description of Figure 1 ¶
¶
2 → Description of Figure 2 ¶
¶
3 → Description of Figure 3 ¶
¶
4 → Description of Figure 5 ¶
¶
```

After the macro is complete, clicking on `"Description of Figure 1"` will go to bookmark `Figure_01` which exists later in the same document.  I appreciate any help that anyone can give!

Comment: I recommend you look at the Cross-Reference functionality, because that is, essentially, what you're looking for - no need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

We can't just go ahead and write it for you, that is not the nature of the site, however, I don't want to tell you to go off and come back with some more effort and we'll support that.

I want to provide some pointers for you to get you going. Once you have got so far but are getting stuck on specific issues (e.g. 'why do I get error X' or 'why is my loop not capturing everything'), that's the time this site will shine for you and give great support!

So where to start? I'm going to assume non VBA experience and the below a crash course.

First we need a procedure that we can run. In Word press Alt+F11, this opens the VBE (VBA-Editor)

From the project window on the top left side (usually) double click on 'ThisDocument' and the main window will become a space for us to write code. The first first thing to write at the very top is `Option Explicit`, this is telling the VBA runtime that all variables must be declared, which is good practice.

Next below that enter: -

```
Public Sub CreateLinks()

End Sub
```

You have now created a procedure called `CreateLinks`, while your insertion point (vertical blinking line) is between these two lines of code you can push F8 to step through code line by line, or F5 to run it all in one go.

That's the start of everything. Now what you need to do is.

1. Connect to the document
2. Find the text to link to
3. Find the text to link from
4. Create link
5. Repeat steps 2 - 5 until all links are done.

That should bring you to your answer.

As further pointers/hints to help you: -

The `Application` holds a collection of documents, you could look through them or open your document to connect to it

a `Document` has a collection of bookmarks and hyperlinks, you can loop through these while getting to your goal

`Selection` is that active selected text

I hope this is of help.